# Generating absurd output

Tags: c, io, printf, output

I wrote the following code but it is generating absurd output values. I can't figure out what's wrong in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t, n, i, count;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        long long a[n], limit;

        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            scanf("%lld", &a[i]);

        count = 1;
        limit = a[1];
        for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] < limit)
            {
                count++;
                limit = a[i];
            }
        }

        printf("%lld\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**INPUT :-**

> 3
>   1
>   10
>   3
>   8 3 6
>   5
>   4 5 1 2 3

**OUTPUT :-**

> -4621320042389176319
>   4615368115365085186
>   -4621320334446952446

Please give the explanation for whatever problem with my code.

Comment: Your range (and thus the indexing inside the loop) for both `for` loops are wrong. You are accessing out of bounds of array `a`. Array index range is `0... N-1`.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two issues:
First, in C array indexes start with 0, not 1. So it must be

```
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%lld", &a[i]);

    count = 1;
    limit = a[0];
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] < limit)
        {
            count++;
            limit = a[i];
        }
    }
```

Second, you call `printf("%lld\n", count);` but `count` is an 'ordinary int', so it should be `printf("%d\n", count);`

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the garbage output, but I see two occurrences of UB in your code, caused by accessing the `a` array out of bounds:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   scanf("%lld", &a[i]);
```

...and...

```
for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{         
    if(a[i] < limit)
    {
            count++;
            limit = a[i];
    }
}
```

In the first case you're iterating over the **[1, `n`]** range *(where `n` is inclusive)*. In the second case you're iterating over the **[2, `n`]** range *(where `n` is inclusive)*.

But your `a` array has `n` elements, so its range is **[0, n)**, with `n` **exclusive**.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
int count;
```

this code

```
printf("%lld\n", count);
```

is undefined behavior.

Per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the format specifier `"ll"` is for `long long int` types:

> ll (ell-ell)   Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X`
>   conversion specifier applies to a `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` argument; or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a
>   pointer to a `long long int` argument.

And

> If  a  conversion  specification  is  invalid,  the  behavior  is 
>   undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong length modifier here:

```
 printf("%lld\n", count);
```

Doing so invokes undefined behaviour, so anything could be printed — anything could happen.

To print an `int` (which `count` is) just use `d` without any length modifiers.

```
 printf("%d\n", count);
```

(or define `count` to be a `long long int`, which is what `lld` expects).